# How do I change Button Text color onclick event(asp.net, C#)using Css file?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have CSS classfile. So when I click on  button the buttontext should be in green.

```
.buttongreen
{
    color:green;    
}
```

Comment: You want this in code behind ?

Comment: yes ,using CssClass file , marrying with Asp.net  call on click event of button

Comment: Have u tried my answer ?

Comment: whre is your answer, anyways its done by the way thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my answer using cssClass OF button. Not sure but this may help you ..

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.CssClass = "buttongreen";
}
```

Comment: not hover change color Button Click Event Color Change.

Comment: it works thank u . what to do  if i want to change 2 button text , using only present CssClass file,  i mean if i change color to red in css file , it applies on all the  button text.

Comment: as above have used button.cssClass, you just specify button names whose color you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without changing any cssClass.
You can change your button text color like this

```
void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        btn.Forecolor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Or you can change your button background color like this:

```
void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn.Backgroundcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: i think we can do change by this way you showed. but i am trying to do with using CssClass file .

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change color of button in code behind than do this

```
btnName.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green");
```

Here `btnName` is `ID` of button.

And if you want to add a class than do this

```
btnName.Attributes.Add("class", "buttongreen");
```

Comment: Please see the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Using javascript

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function changeColor()
   ```

   {

   ```
   document.getElementById("buttonName").className = "MyClass";
   ```

   }

   ```
   <script>
   ```

call this function OnClientClick

2. In code behind

   btnName.Attributes.Add("class", "buttongreen");

Comment: i am trying to do with Using CssClass file .. if u can help me pls

Answer (score 1):

Change the foreground color of your button text from OnClick event.

```
button.Forecolor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

I hope this will work for you without CSS.